# Can't use DT package due to missing jquery calls

Tags: r, dt

I am trying to use the `DT` library for the first time, but seem to be running into difficulties even with the smallest example?

```
library(DT)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))
datatable(df)
#Warning messages:
#1: In file.create(to[okay]) :
#  cannot create file 'lib/dt-core-1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', reason 'No such file or directory'
#2: In file.create(to[okay]) :
#  cannot create file 'lib/dt-core-1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css', reason 'No such file or directory'
#3: In file.create(to[okay]) :
#  cannot create file 'lib/dt-core-1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.extra.css', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

I have just reinstalled it. Here's the installed version and my sessionInfo:

```
> packageVersion("DT")
[1] ‘0.2’

> sessionInfo()
> R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
> 
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
> LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
> States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
> LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
> 
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
> datasets  methods   base     
> 
> other attached packages: [1] DT_0.2
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] htmlwidgets_0.7
> magrittr_1.5    htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.2     yaml_2.1.13    
> Rcpp_0.12.7     jsonlite_1.1    [8] digest_0.6.10
```

Checked github issues... nothing reported there. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the warnings when you create an object like `dt = datatables(df)`? Or only when it then creates the web page via `print(dt)`? Is it an issue with your temp storage folder device being full?

Comment: Are you running the R session in a location you have privileges to write? It looks like DT temporarily copies some files to your current working directory. Perhaps try re-opening the R session in a different location, or using `setwd()` to change directories?

Comment: @Spacedman when I `dt = datatable(df)` I don't get an error, but calling `dt` or `print(dt)` gives same error. @KeithHughitt, yes I have permissions, anyway tried `setwd()` into a folder I'm sure I can write to and same error.

Comment: Maybe a relevant detail, I just installed new version of RStudio  day before yesterday (latest version)

Comment: @user5249203 Yes, I'm admin.

Comment: @user5249203 Yup, ran Rgui as admin and had the same problems.

Comment: @user5249203 great ideas man (or woman)!... unfortunately no results. it's getting uncomfortable for me to continue to shoot you down... perhaps it's destiny that I don't use the DT package. I've been using R for years now and never had a need for it, and in fact for my immediate use case I don't need it any more... so feel free to give up on me.

Comment: Sure. Not a problem. I will give up. was puzzled when `sessioninfo()` looks exactly same on my end and DT working as expected ! Good Luck, post answer if you figure it out.